# exec(open('/tmp/tmpu7edmqsu.py'.encode('utf-8')).read()) on PyQGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I tried to load csv layer using this script:

```
file = "/home/ayato/Desktop/26mei.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"
uri = file % (",", "x", "y")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "asd", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

and I got this in the console:

```
exec(open('/tmp/tmpu7edmqsu.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
```

How to solve it?

PS:
I used QGIS 3.0.2 in Ubuntu 18. I also tried with the same QGIS version in Windows 8.1 and had the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to solve this by adding `file://` as a prefix to the file path. So the complete code looks like this:

```
file = "file:///home/ayato/Desktop/26mei.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"
uri = file % (",", "x", "y")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "asd", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

PS:
If you want to run a standalone PyQGIS script and want to specify relative path instead of absolute path, just remove the slashes. The code will look like this:

```
file = "file:26mei.csv?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s"
uri = file % (",", "x", "y")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "asd", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behaviour - you are editing your script in a temporary file, and that line is the Python console loading and running your script when you hit the "Run Script" button.

If you save the file to another location you'll see that, for example `exec(open('/me/Documents/loadcsv.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())`.

If your script isn't loading the layer then that's another problem - check that `vlayer.isValid()` is `True` - there may be other problems but the Python console telling you what it is doing isn't one of them.

Comment: Oh, good it's normal. The `vlayer.isValid()` returned `False` so I think the problem is in the process of loading layer. I just tried to add `file://` as a prefix to the file directory and it works. Thank you. Btw, why the console did not returned an error when something unexpected happened?